# How would I create a div and place the 'brands' data from JSON into it?

Tags: javascript, json, api, fetch-api

Currently, I'm trying to learn how to access data from an API and place it into a div onto my html. I'm using fetch, but I'm not sure where to go after I stringify the data. I want to access the 'Brands' data from the API and place it into my html.

```
fetch("http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
    (data) => {
        JSON.stringify(data)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data) to learn JavaScript fetch.

Here's a working snippet (although it won't work from SO).

```js
const url = 'http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json';
fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    let products = data;
    return products.map(function(product) {
      console.log(product.brand);
      //$("#listOfBrands").append(product.brand); // do as you will
    })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

```html
<div id="listOfBrands"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's more so being able to access the different data from JSON is what I get stuck on, are there any references/articles you recommend for that?

Comment: That's pretty basic JavaScript - try the JSON or OOP JavaScript tutorials on W3Schools. Also, please accept my answer if you believe it is helpful :)